# Implementing a Lazy Time Series in Scala

Tags: scala, data-structures, types, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement a Traversable data structure in Scala which represents a transformation (represented by `fn`) to an `initial` value over a `TimeInterval` with a defined `Period` step. Under the hood, the way this works is currently by lazily calculating the value of the function returned by `fn` (called `mapper`) when it is requested by a call to `apply(i: Ind)`

Although the underlying `cache` is technically mutable, values will only ever be calculated once, and I would like this data structure to behave in an immutable fashion and to return new instances of `LazyTimeSeries`

```
case class LazyTimeSeries[+A, B] (
  interval: TimeInterval,
  initial: A
)(private val fn: (TimeInterval, A) => (Int, LocalDate) => B) 
    extends TimeSeries[A, B]
    with GenericTraversableTemplate[(Int, (LocalDate, B)), LazyTimeSeries[A, B]]
{
    private val mapper = fn(interval, initial)
    private val cache = new mutable.HashMap[Int, (LocalDate, Eval[B])]

    private def pairAt(i: Int): (LocalDate, Eval[B]) = pairAt(i, interval(i))
    private def pairAt(i: Int, d: LocalDate): (LocalDate, Eval[B]) =
        cache.getOrElseUpdate(i, (d, Eval.later(mapper(i, d))))

    def apply(i: Int): Option[(LocalDate, B)] =
        if (i < 0 || i >= interval.size) None
        else Some(pairAt(i) match { case (d, e) => (d, e.value) })

    def foreach[U](f: ((Int, (LocalDate, B))) => U): Unit =
        interval.indices.map(i => (i, pairAt(i))).foreach({ 
            case (i, (d, e)) => e.flatMap(b => { f(i, (d, b)); Eval.later(b) })
        })

}
```

In any case, the issue that I am currently having is that I would like to extend the `GenericTraversableTemplate`, but I am currently getting the following error:

> Error:(18, 58) LazyTimeSeries[A,B] takes no type parameters, expected: one
>     with GenericTraversableTemplate[(Int, (LocalDate, B)), LazyTimeSeries[A, B]]

I've done a bit of digging about implementing `Traversable` but I'm having a bit of a mental block as far as the type system goes and how best to go about implementing a corresponding builder for this type of data structure. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `LazyTimeSeries` is a `case class`, and as such, you cannot really extend it.

Comment: You just can't extend a case class with another case class, @BobDalgleish.  Extending it with a regular class is just fine, and you can manually create extractors to make it act like a case class.

Comment: Why would it be a case class at all? This means that any two `LazyTimeSeries` with the same interval and initial value are equal.